# <li> items which go to line when resizing my window

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a menu bar. Actually i have this in
[full window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWcoZ.png). And when i have resized my window i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGhgI.png).
I'm using this HTML code :

```
<!-- MenuHome.php -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vues/include/styleMenu.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this CSS code :

```
body{
    background: #0b0b0b;
}

.contenairMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-150%);
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.menu::after{
    content : '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.menu:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
```

My main object is when i'm using my site on a little window (like on smartphone, tablet or tiny screen) i would like to have a resizing menu bar to match with the window size to make it "responsive" (always in a single line). But instead my menu bar is like the second screenshot. I don't know how can i do this and if someone can help me on how i can do it.

This is how i'm using my code :

HTML

```
<!-- ViewHome.php -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Home - My Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vues/include/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="contenairMenu">
      <?php include('Vues/include/menu.php') ?> //-> menu.php is the first block of code that i have wrote above
    </div>
    <div class="contenair">
      <h1 class="big-title">Or Clic here :</h2>
      <h3 class="cmmc">Start</h3>
    </div>
    <img src="Vues/images/sky.png" class="sky" alt="">
    <img src="Vues/images/bg2.png" class="bg2" alt="">
    <img src="Vues/images/fg.png" class="fg" alt="">
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

The linked css :

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contenairMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-150%);
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.contenair{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    line-height: 4rem;
    top : calc(50% - 2rem);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.cmmc{
    z-index: 30;
    top : calc(50% - 2rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 5px solid white;
}

.fg{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 2000px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
}

.bg2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 2100px;
    bottom: 38px;
    z-index: 19;
}

.sky{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 2100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you have any suggestion,improve or tutorial for my code i take all advises or thing that can help me. Thank you.
Have a nice day.

Comment: What you are looking for is "Fluid Typography". You actually need to make the font-size responsive and not the elements themself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use responsive font sizes like vw

```css
body{
    background: #0b0b0b;
}

.contenairMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-150%);
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 0 5vw;
}

.menu::after{
    content : '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.menu:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}




@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contenairMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-150%);
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.contenair{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    line-height: 4rem;
    top : calc(50% - 2rem);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.cmmc{
    z-index: 30;
    top : calc(50% - 2rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3vw;
    border: .5vw solid white;
}

.fg{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 2000px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
}

.bg2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 2100px;
    bottom: 38px;
    z-index: 19;
}

.sky{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 2100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

ul{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!-- MenuHome.php -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the hamburger menu ? have You tried that ?
Example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp

The idea is to hide the menu on mobile screens and show it on button click. Mobile menu will be styled like a column instead of the row.

If You really have to align the menu items in a row on mobile screens than You need to understand that the last item is wrapping on the next line because there is not enough space for him. You could probably fix that by making the nav items smaller :)

Please note that the code quality on the above site is not perfect however You will get the idea

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to set the ul to flex then to nowrap but the other problem is that you hard-coded the font size and padding so i changed to relative(em) also if you want to have more control on the size of the font and padding you should write media queries for them

```css
body{
    background: #0b0b0b;
}


ul {

  display : flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.contenairMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-150%);
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0 0.1em;
}

.menu::after{
    content : '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.menu:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vues/include/styleMenu.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```